# Как сделать нестандартный блок в css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

я новичок и на фрилансе, столкнулся с таким заказом и стало интересно, как сделать такой нестандартный сайдбар и  его элементов при наведении, перерыл весь интернет, но не нашел помогите пожалуйста реализовать этот блок и его элементы, спасибо!

[image: Левый сайт бар и его элементы при наведении]

Comment: Надо изучить как в JavaScript работать с DOM 1. как получать элементы со страницы по CSS селектору 2. Как на DOM - элементы ставить слушатели событий 3. Как DOM - элементам добавлять/удалять CSS класс. 4. И изучить как работают циклы

Comment: Это я написал о том, чему нужно научиться, чтобы меню менялись(услуги, о компании, контакты).Что именно в верстке непонятно? В чём у вас проблема? Покажите вашу реализацию.

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, Скорее всего, "рисовка"

Comment: ваш слайд-бар должен быть фиксированным?

Comment: ...и сайд-бар должен быть на всю высоту экрана?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин да нужна именно рисовка  сайдбара и его элементов  если обычный блок  ровный то на фото он с волнами и  неровностями, простите что неправильно объяснил